# 'reject!' returns 'nil', but it's actually deleting the object from the array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a hash `@log`, whose key is a date and whose value is an array of `LogItem` objects, each of which has date and name.

I tried to remove an object from a value of the hash, and return the removed object. I thought `reject!` and `delete_if` methods return the object they removed from the array, and tried this:

```
def remove_logItem(name, date)
  @log[date] #=> {2008-09-12 => "Apple"}
  array = @log[date].reject! {|logItem| logItem.name == name}
  @log[date] #=> []
  array[0].nil? #=> true
  return array[0]
end
```

It returns `nil`, but it still removes the object. Am I misunderstanding something? If so, is there other way to return the object after removing it from the array?

Comment: It is hard to follow what you have from just the inspections you gave at some points within the method. Describe the initial value of `@log`, and how you called the method `remove_logItem` (of course with the arguments).

Answer (score 2):

This is the [documented behaviour for `reject!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21):

> Deletes every element of `self` for which the block evaluates to true, if no changes were made returns `nil`.

If you want to separate the objects based on criteria you might want to use [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
@log[date] #=> {2008-09-12 => "Apple"}
removed, @log[date] = @log[date].partition {|logItem| logItem.name == name}
```

Where now you have, at the least, an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

you could loop over the Array and when the loop is equal to the value youre trying to delete and retrieve, use an if statement within the loop to set the variable equal to the one you want to delete and then delete it

heres some sudo code

```
@foo.each do |hash| 
 if hash == my_hash_to_delete
  my_deleted = my_hash_to_delete
  @foo.delete(hash)
  break
 end
end
```

edit: added break, you dont want to continue to loop once youve finished the task